# How to convert a string with hexadecimal characters in a string to a full unicode in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

After searching around for about two hours i'll finally ask here. Im using Python 2.7 with the csv module, which unfortunately doesn't support unicode output, so when i'm reading something like u'Französisch' (means French in German) from the file, it gives back a 'Franz\xc3\xb6sisch'. Does a function exist, with which I can easily convert the string with a hexaecimal escape character back to a normal unicode (u'Französisch')?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the bytes from the file. Use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) to open the file with a given encoding (e.g. UTF-8) so that you read text instead.

Also, [read this](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).